# merge two distribution list in outlook 2007

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007, contacts

I have two distribution list in outlook contacts. I would like to make it one. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new contact list, go to Select Members, at the bottom, type in the names of the distribution lists you wish to add (must be perfect), then click OK. You'll see the distribution lists appear underneath as part of the new distribution list.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found is to redo the list. Hope some one else has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just got it.

1. I made a new folder for contacts.
2. Dropped the distribution lists into the new folder for contacts. I even added a few separate contacts.
3. Then went to file -> new ->distribution list
4. under the address book drop down change it to the new folder you created in step one.
5. Select all the contact by clicking on the first entry in the list hold shift while you click on the last one.
6. Then click on the members button. It will then add them to the list.
7. just save the list and your done.